# SalesForce integration with Expression Engine has anyone integrated this?

Tags: salesforce

Here is a brief background on the issue. Client has force.com CRM and posts and manages all its ticket orders for upcoming events in Salesforce. What I would like to do is integrate EE to manage and display all the events. Is it possible to be able to pull those events from object tags within Salesforce such as date, images and descriptions, and display that data in EE channels. So basically a nice responsive front end website in EE with Salesforce data. We have looked at site.com but is too expensive. Would I need a plugin for accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I have never used SalesForce, but here's the breakdown. Use their API's:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/

Then simply write a module triggered by a cron job (curl the ACTion ID):

https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/module_tutorial.html

That pulls in the data from SalesForce, and uses the Channel Entries API:

https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/api/api_channel_entries.html

To dump the data in a channel. And Tada! Wish I could give you an experience with this, but I kinda avoid SalesForce like it is the plague. (Maybe it's not so bad?)

Comment: I have forwarded this to the team for review.

Answer (score 0):

The Solspace Team built a SalesForce integration module (not commercial), you can contact them. 
Blog post : [ExpressionEngine + Salesforce](https://solspace.com/blog/entry/expressionengine-salesforce-google-analytics-overbuilding)